# A vitamin supplement can be both water and fat soluble?

Tags: nutrition, dermatology, multi-vitamin

How can these nutritional facts included supplement can be defined? Water-soluble or fat-soluble?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Vitamins A, D, E and K are fat-soluble.

In solid food, you can trivially have both fat- and water-soluble molecules in a solid state.

In purely liquid food, there needs to be an [emulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion) of a lipohibic and lipophilic phase to solute the fat- and water soluble vitamins. Milk would be one example of such an emulsion.